# Angular Material and Jasmine : " No provider for InjectionToken MdDialogData! "

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, angular-material2, mddialog

I have a component which is meant to be used in an Angular Material MdDialog :

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, public dialogRef: 
MdDialogRef<MyComponent>) {
...
  }


}
```

I am trying to Unit Test it with Jasmine :

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SharedTestingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  ...
  
});
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error :

> Error: No provider for InjectionToken MdDialogData!

SharedTestingModule imports and exports my custom Angular Material module, which itself imports and exports MdDialogModule.

How can I get rid of this error?

Thank you very much!

```
Angular 4.2.4
Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.7
Jasmine 2.5.3
```

Comment: You always is going to get a error of this type if the injectable, in this case  MdDialogData, is null or not defined (JS) or one of the components of MatDialog is null and then it can not be created.

Example:

`let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteDialogComponent, {
      data: row.name   //<-if here you put i.e 4 value you get  Error: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData, in this case DeleteDialogComponent inherits from MatDialogRef and MatDialogRef has MAT_DIALOG_DATA as injectable!
    });`

Answer (score 172, accepted):

I added this :

```
providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
    // { provide: MdDialogRef, useValue: {} }, --> deprecated
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} } ---> now
]
```

And it works :)

Thanks for your help @methgaard!

Comment: My pleasure, glad i could help! :)

Comment: `MD_DIALOG_DATA` got renamed to `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` in more recent Angulars.

Comment: you added this, where?

Comment: @ShawnMercado In `TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})`

Comment: I am going to put this here, just i case some poor soul encounters the same issue as me.
I was getting the error `cannot read property of undefined` due to using `userClass` instead of `useValue` for `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`.

Comment: `MdDialogRef` is now `MatDialogRef`

Comment: This answer is outdated, see other comments

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks. Can you please explain why it solve the problem?

Answer (score 102):

For Angular 5 with latest Material Component

```
 import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

and

```
 providers: [
     { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
     { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
 ]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.. couldn't figure out how to import `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` from `@angular/Material`

Comment: This works perfectly to. I'm using `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any` in my DialogRef component. I forgot to declare this in my spec. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

try this

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
     SharedTestingModule,
   ],
   declarations: [
     MyComponent,
   ],
   providers: [ <-- here
    {
     provide: MdDialogData,
     useValue: {},
    }
   ] <-- to here 
 })
 .compileComponents();
}));
```

let me know how it goes

Answer (score 13):

as an update, this is also replicated for those who use the tags with the prefix "Mat"

```
providers: [{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {}}, 
{provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}}]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Angular Optional decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional), I faced this problem before so

if the component is not used as a ***popup*** try this snippet

```
constructor(
  @Optional() public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PopupComponent>,
  @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
) {}
```

Comment: Worked for me!!! Had a component that I was loading in normal way and also loading the same as a dialog sometimes. So the  *@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any   * was null in normal loading and it would not work.

Answer (score 4):

you can inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA / MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA in jasmine tests without specifying a provider. you must simply ensure that the value being injected is non-null. if it is null, the compiler mistakes the null value for a non-existing provider and you get the provider not found error.

Comment: This was exactly my problem (using Angular 8.x)

Answer (score 2):

try add in your `<x>.component.spec.ts` under `providers`:

```
{ provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} }
```

in some cases you need also:

```
{ provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
```

(this way working in my angular 11 project)

Answer (score 0):

No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!, This error will occur when we run test cases, When we use  matdialog reference with @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public value: string, in the respected component.

Add below code in spec.ts file

providers: [MatDialogModule,
{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
{ provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }]